# How to handle Android's Back Button click in a single HTML page webapp using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I read from the documentation that we can handle the back button click using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true); 
function backKeyDown() { 
     // Call my back key code here.
    alert('go back!');
}
```

My concern is that I have a single HTML5 web page in which I have multiple `div` tags which I animate using jQuery as per the navigation option selected by the user from the menu options.

How can I, in this single page webapp, handle the back button click using PhoneGap and show the user the previously animated `div`. Clicking on the back button again would again take him to the previous `div` of the current previous `div` :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a global array variable as

`var myStack = new Array();`

Then whenever I clicked on the `div` tag, I inserted the function prototype along with the arguments inside the `myStack` variable. For eg:

`myStack.push(\"myfunction(args1, args2);\");`

Then, using the code which I posted in my question, inside the `BackButton` handler, I wrote the following code:

```
var divToShow = myStack.pop();
eval(divToShow);
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I will just post my overall idea of handling this situation. Hope you can improvise and change it to suit your needs.

1. Have a global variable to remember the current div id that is
   visible. For example, when a menu item x is clicked, set this global
   variable to the div id that is currently visible (before showing the next div corresponding to menu item x).
2. When the back button is pressed, use the global variable's value to identify the previous div. Hide the current div and show the previous one.

Comment: I was actually thinking something in this direction... Actually was planning to implement a Linked List in JavaScript.. which just adds nodes to it as the selections are made and removed as back button is pressed.. I was looking here for someone who have had came across such similar problem and found a solution.. hoping that I don't reinvent the wheel :-)

Comment: may be i should implement a 'Stack' in JavaScript which Pushes/Popes the ids of the div tag !!!

Comment: IMO, you dont have to overly complicate things.Its just a matter of updating a variable whenever a menu item is clicked.. Or checkout jquery mobile ,which supports page system. It may suit you. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Comment: I don't however understand what you mean by updating a variable... I believe I'll be required to store many values and so would require some sort of data structure...

Answer (score 1):

I did an implementation in a similarly structured phonegap app. My situation was a bit more complex because I was loading in html as well as external data via ajax (rather than just unhiding divs). I created a global array called history which I used to keep track of current position as well as previous positions (position here being the most recent ajax function called, so the array was actually storing function names as text). The right sequence and combination of .pop and .push array methods got me a fully functioning js back button that scaled nicely and handled any kind of back and forth navigation I could think of.